# Making a page to reload it's cache

Tags: java, javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have situation , where in application I have to select a theme then have to reload cache , I want to be able to do this using code instead of asking using to clear cache.

I found out that clearing cache is not possible , but it is possible to make a page which will validate for change in resources it uses and reloads them if they are changed. I am only targeting IE and Chrome.

any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some strings to names of images and css/js files. For instance, changing this:

```
<script src="/path/to/file/misc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

on this:

```
<script src="/path/to/file/misc.js?123123" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It can be a timestamp, as an example, or any other string. If You will add it like this, browser should download all files with changed names once more.

Comment: Sorry for late response , Thanks Krzysztof.